# Pandas rename multilevel looking column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which its column names have changed to

```
MultiIndex([(     'ID',       ''),
            ('Probability',   'mean'),
            ('Probability', 'median'),
            ('Uncertainty',   'mean'),
            ('Uncertainty', 'median')],
          )
```

because I did

```
data[data["ID"].notnull()].groupby(["ID"]).agg({"Probability":["mean", "median"], "Uncertainty":["mean", "median"]}).reset_index()
```

I want to rename the column names to something like this:

```
["ID", "Probability_mean", "Probability_median", "Uncertainty_mean", "Uncertainty_median"]
```

I can rename each original column name individually but I can't rename them together. I also tried flattening the dataframe as I thought it was a multi index or a multilevel. Although it looks so, it is not one. Most of the multi index functionalities don't work for it. Is there a way to rename these columns? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using `pd.__version__ > 0.25.0` you can create a dictionary with `NamedAggs`.

Before `reset_index` you can use `str.join` to collapse the MultiIndex after the groupby. Then `reset_index`. This avoids issues with `'ID'`.  Also, there is no need to drop the null group keys as `groupby` will ignore these by default.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
N = 6
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.arange(N)//2, 
                   'Probability': np.random.normal(0,1,N),
                   'Uncertainty': np.random.normal(0,1,N)})
agg_d = {'Probability': ['mean', 'median'], 'Uncertainty': ['mean', 'median']}
```

#### Code:

#### >= 0.25.0

```
d = {f'{k}_{x}': pd.NamedAgg(column=k, aggfunc=x) for k,v in agg_d.items() for x in v}
df.groupby('ID').agg(**d).reset_index()
```

#### < 0.25.0

```
res = df.groupby('ID').agg(agg_d)
res.columns = ['_'.join(tup) for tup in res.columns]
res = res.reset_index()
```

#### Output:

```
   ID  Probability_mean  Probability_median  Uncertainty_mean  Uncertainty_median
0   0          0.795119            0.795119          0.466417            0.466417
1   1          0.150184            0.150184         -0.132942           -0.132942
2   2          1.250202            1.250202         -0.102760           -0.102760
```

Comment: Wow! Both solutions work! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, I'm back just to tell you that I love your NamedAgg solution! Thanks again!